# How to render multiple views using Node+Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a header.html and a footer.html which I would like to be rendered along with other views. I want to accomplish this using Node+Express. 
I tried to render views in the following way but clearly it doesn't work:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('header');
    res.render('home');
    res.render('footer');
});
```

Comment: Render home and include in it the header and footer isn't an option?

Comment: The problem is I need each of the views to decoupled from each other so that they can be reused for other purposes later.

Comment: But you can 'include' the html or the jade and keep the 3 components decoupled

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a template engine to your project.
You can use [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/) for instance, it works very nice and it is well documented.

The example below, shows you how to set it and how you can call partial views from a layout or master page.

Install it by doing `npm install swig --save` on your project root.
You need to install an additional library called consolidate which acts as interface among different template engine libraries, it is kind of standard in express applications.

```
npm install consolidate --save
```

require the library in your main script with

```
consolidate = require('consolidate');
swig = require('swig');
```

Configure it as follows:

```
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // set your view path correctly here
```

Then you can render a page as:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});
});
```

([Example taken from Swig's author, Paul Armstrong github page](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/tree/master/examples/express))
Layout.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="/people">People</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section role="main">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Index.html:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
```

This way, you can decoupled your views as you need :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug), you can take an advantage of include feature, like [@Kangcor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4261197/kangcor) suggestion

**home.pug**

```
html
  head
    include ./path/to/header.pug
    title= title
  body
    ...
    include ./path/to/footer.pug
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handlebars partial views
Here is a well documented library
https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#basic-partials

Install hbs
https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/#npm-or-yarn-recommended

```
npm install handlebars
```

Configure Handlebars

```
// import library on the your start js file ie: app.js || index.js
let hbs = require('hbs');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Create your partial views ie: header.hbs and footer.hbs on the partials directory

Create a file layout.hbs and you can call the partial view as follows

```
<div>
{{> header}}
{{> body}}
{{> footer}}
</div>
```

Then when calling

```
res.render("home", {});
```

home.hbs will be mapped as the body and the footer and header will be added to the layout.