# node.js - express - render multiple views

Tags: node.js, express

I'ld like to send two successive ejs page to the client using the following code:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('yourDemandIsBeingProceed.ejs');
  //some code which require time (open an external programm, run a script, edit a response)
  res.render('hereIsYourResult.ejs');
  res.end();
});
```

So, once once the client post his form, he receives a page asking him to wait for a few seconds and then the page containing the response is send.

any suggestion?

many thx

Comment: I forgot ot mention that i'ld like to avoid using socket.io

Comment: This is not how http works. Once you execute `res.render` the connection is closed and you cannot send any more data to the client.

Comment: If you use pug, take a look my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644185/2368696)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render multiple views using Node+Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266446/how-to-render-multiple-views-using-nodeexpress)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have client-side code in `yourDemandIsBeingProceed.ejs` when the page loads that performs a get/post request to a different endpoint. When the result from that is received, hide/show different elements inside `yourDemandIsBeingProceed.ejs` so it looks more like `hereIsYourResult.ejs`

Answer (score 0):

What you really should do is have the user submit information via front end AJAX and put up a loading graphic until the JSON response gets back. AJAX was developed for situations exactly like this.